# What is the behavior of scanf when using "%s" format specifier for reading in single char?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

char a;
scanf("%s", &a);

return 0;
}
```

Works for me, but I wonder if in other context there might be any unexpected results.

Comment: I'd use getchar() for this, to be sure... I'd expect that as scanf does not know what kind of address it got, it will write to memory it shouldn't...

Comment: The Standard states very clearly that mixing wrong specifiers and types is undefined behaviour. What happens in practice in any arbitrary context is supremely and dangerously uninteresting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this code for example -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    char a;
    char b = '1';
    char c = '1';
    scanf("%s", &a);

    printf("%c = %c\n", b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

You would expect it to print `1 = 1`, but just now when I ran it, it printed `= 1` (at least in my compiler, don't expect anything stable from it)

scanf writes a string to the address of a, expecting enough space was allocated there (which is wrong in this case), this string has the input char and the null terminator. The null terminator overwrites some other memory, in my case - that of b. This is undefined behavior - don't do that (at least not while expecting it to make any sense).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted to know. And I never do that, I was just wondering why compiler didn't give any warning.

Comment: I guess that a warning can be implemented if the compiler sees that a char* passed to scanf comes from taking an address of a char variable (and not from memory allocation, array, or string literal), but this seems like minor thing and it's also possibly legal (if you define char str[N] and pass &(str[0]))

Answer (score 1):

Either use format `%c` to match single `char`, or use `%s` to match a string of non-space characters.

Mixing them up (like in your code) is undefined behavior, **anything may happen**.